# Kendo grid format time issue in date column

Tags: javascript, date, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid, it has a date column. I want to show date and time there. I am using below format in column definition,

`format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}"`

In modal I used date type `Updated_Date: { type: "date" }`

Output date is coming as '10-Oct-2013 12:00:00 AM', but actual date returned via ajax call is "Updated_Date":"2013-10-10T05:02:40.44"

What to do to show the correct time in Grid like 10-Oct-2013 05:02:40 AM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two fields that are commonly confused:

- [format](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#configuration-format) : Specifies the format, which is used to format the value of the DateTimePicker displayed in the input.
- [parseFormats](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker#configuration-parseFormats): Specifies the formats, which are used to parse the value set with value() method or by direct input.

So actually you need to define a parseFormat because of the `T` between date and time that makes the format not being a default one:

Try:

```
columns   : [
    ...
    {
        field       : "Date",
        title       : "Date",
        format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"]
    }
]
```

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Ahq6s/

Comment: I tried this //format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
            //parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ss"] but not working.

Comment: Please, check the JSFiddle that I've added in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Just had the exact same problem.  It is because the grid is not recognising the field as a date.  You need to add the "type" as follows:

```
columns   : [
...
{
    field       : "Date",
    title       : "Date",
    type        : "date",
    format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
    parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"]
}
```

]