# Parsing dates in kendo grid - mvvm binding

Tags: html, json, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here you can see the binding for a kendo ui grid:

```
<div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: reportSource, visible: reportVisible"
    data-columns='[{"field":"TIME", "title": "TIME", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"]}, {"field":"LOGIN", "title": "LOGIN"}, {"field":"DEAL", "title": "DEAL"}]'>
</div>
```

As you see I'm trying to parse dates. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19318990/104969) but when I try to apply this in mvvm binding, the single quotes of 'T' char cause trouble. 
How can I parse dates in mvvm binding?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: well it seems like you are dealing with just another attribute no ? so maybe try replacing your single quote with &#39;

Comment: @MustafaP I added the solution as an answer. Kolay gelsin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle to solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BYqpL/3/
The key point is:

> The build-in dataSource data parsing is executed only when the data comes from a transport

and also we have to define the parse method for the field in schema.

```
"CreatedDate": { 
    type: "date", 
    parse: function(value) { 
        return kendo.parseDate(value, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. Sanada kolay gelsin hocam.

Comment: by the way, did you notice when parse function is deleted from CreatedDate, date format stays same. `"format": "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}"`  works correctly without parse function

Comment: Nope. See the time part of date. It didn't parse correctly the part after "T". I see 12:00:00 in the CreatedDate column which is not the expected value if I remove the parse function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with an attribute, try replacing your single quote with

```
&#39;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and this article helped me alot
http://blog.falafel.com/passing-dates-kendo-ui-aspnet/

Changes i made in my code:

1. in parameterMap

   if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {

   data.model_date_field = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data.model_date_field), "G");

   return data;
   }
2. in model definition

   fields: {
          model_date_field: { nullable: true, type: "date" }
   }